# Best way to interact with database in java desktop application

Tags: java, database, architecture

I want to develop a desktop application in java.
I don't like pure JDBC - it is too low level.
I don't like Hibernate, it is very tricky to use Hibernate in desktop application.
And also I don't want to write tons of xml configs...

Any suggestions?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Maybe you can tell us about your *wants*?

Answer (score 0):

You can try MyBatis : http://code.google.com/p/mybatis/

For a quick description you can check the Wikipedia article : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MyBatis

Answer (score 0):

You can use Spring JDBC, it's simple , powerful and clean.

You will have to write little XML or try annotations.

If you don't know spring, it's worth investigating.

You can also try mybatis but there is XML.

Regards

Philippe

Answer (score 0):

If you want to control full control over the SQL database schema, use [MyBatis](http://www.mybatis.org/core/).and the other way choose [Java Persistence API(JPA)](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javaee/jpa-137156.html) that is standard and simple to use.